# What's the equivalent terminal command for removing users/groups from a folder recursively?

Tags: terminal, finder, permission

When I remove a user or a group permission from a folder and all its children files and folders, this is what I do:

- Right click the folder
- Click "Get info"
- Unlock the padlock (typing my admin password)
- Remove users and or groups
- Press "Apply to all enclosed items" and confirm

How can I do this from the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `chmod` command, with the `-a` flag to delete access control list entries, and the `-R` flag to do so recursively.

For example:

`$ chmod -R -a "admin allow read" foldername`

would make all files in `foldername` read-only for the admin user (because you're removing the "allow read" property for "admin".

`$ chmod -R -a "joe allow delete" foldername`

would prevent user joe from deleting any file in `foldername`.

To add properties back, use `+a` instead of `-a`.

For more details and examples, see the `chmod` manpage, or [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/).